# Gurobi : Adding a constraint with lower and upper bounds

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

I am trying to add a constraint containing lower and upper bounds into my linear programming problem.

```
con1 = m3.addConstr(500 <= 52*x1 + 89*x2 + 57*x3 + 147*x4 + 53*x5 <= 3000, name="con1")
```

This is the code that I used. Although this is a valid syntax, I am unable to get any solution to my problem. Am I doing things correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a range constraint; here is the syntax:

```
con1 = m3.addRange(52*x1 + 89*x2 + 57*x3 + 147*x4 + 53*x5, 500, 3000 name="con1")
```

or

```
con1 = m3.addConstr(52*x1 + 89*x2 + 57*x3 + 147*x4 + 53*x5 == [500, 3000], name="con1")
```

[Here is the documentation](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_addrange.html). These forms are equivalent; they add a ranged variable `r` and the following constraints:

```
52*x1 + 89*x2 + 57*x3 + 147*x4 + 53*x5 + r == 3000
0 <= r <= 3000 - 500
```